# Accept a list of type string from the command line in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I've run in to another problem using argparse.

I'm trying to accept and store a list of string arguments from the command line and accept them without error. At some point I had a solution which required me to to do something similar to the following:

```
backup.py -d C:\blah -d C:\anotherBlah
```

What I would like to do is accept arguments simultaneously without having to specify -d after every input. Example:

```
backup.py -d C:\blah C:\anotherBlah C:\anotherBlahBlah
```

And have them stored as a list of type string rather than individual characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`nargs='+'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
parser.add_argument('-d', nargs='+')
```

---

For example,

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(r'-d C:\blah C:\anotherBlah C:\anotherBlahBlah'.split())
print(args)
```

yields

```
Namespace(d=['C:\\blah', 'C:\\anotherBlah', 'C:\\anotherBlahBlah'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Could you possibly explain to me what this line means? args = parser.parse_args(r'-d C:\blah C:\anotherBlah C:\anotherBlahBlah'.split())

Comment: Usually (as in your program) you would just call `args = parser.parse_args()`. Then the parser would parse `sys.argv`, the arguments passed on the command-line. In order to demonstrate the parser's behaviour, however, instead I passed a list of strings to `parse_args`, which simulate the arguments one might pass on the command-line.

Comment: When an argument is passed `parse_args`, it is parsed instead of `sys.argv`.